# How to make part of the document not reactive in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

Most of the Meteor revolves around collections and cursors and fetching new documents when they appear in collection and match the criteria. Yet I am working with bigger documents, that contain multiple fields and has a deep and not predictable structure. On the top level there is a clear schema, but some subdocuments are unpredictable json data.

But let's look at a simpler example:

```
Reports = new Mongo.collection('reports'); 

Meteor.publish('reports', function() {
    return Reports.find({});
});
```

and then on a client side, I open a report, put it in on screen using rather complicated not-only-html rendering functionality and then there are free text comment field embedded within report. And when they are changed, I want to automatically save them

```
Meteor.call("autosaveReport",reportId,comment);
```

and then there is meteor method that writes in the comment

```
Meteor.methods({
   "autosaveReport": function(reportId,comment) {
        Reports.update({_id:reportId},{$set:{comment:comment}});
   }
);
```

Problem is, that every time comment is autosaved, Meteor Tracker reruns all the subscribtions and finds related to this report. And as report is big and has complicated rendering, that reload is visible for the user and  destroys the purpose of seamless autosaving.

So, question - is it possible to trigger reactivity only on parts of the mongo document? Currently I have solved it by manually comparing old and new document on rendering, and if there is no difference in core, then stopping the re-rendering. That feels odd and against meteor spirit.

Answer (score 1):

In your helper or route that sets the data context for your template, use `{reactive: false}` in the find:

```
return Reports.find(query,{reactive: false});
```

That way the helper won't update when the underlying object changes.

That flag is all or nothing however, it doesn't let you be selective about what changes to observe and which to ignore.